# Javascript count selected radio button attributes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to count the attribute on all selected radio buttons. Using alert, it does find the correct values (e.g. 900, 4680) but doesn't add them together.

Any help would be appreciated, I've probably been staring at it for too long :)

```js
var selectedoptions;
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function( index ){
    var selectedoption = $(this).attr('data-price');
    var selectedoptions = selectedoptions + selectedoption;
  });
});
```

Comment: So what does it do? A working demo would be useful here.

Comment: Not sure of what you're trying to achieve here but you can start trying this.

Replace 

var selectedoptions = selectedoptions + selectedoption;

with

selectedoptions = selectedoptions + selectedoption;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum the total value of `data-price` attributes for the selected radio buttons, you can try with:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  // Start at zero value (if any of the radios is checked).
  var selectedoptions = 0;
  $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function( index ){
    var selectedoption = $(this).data('price'); // Read the value as a number
    selectedoptions += selectedoption;
  });

  // Here you have in selectedoptions the total price.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
  var selectedoptions = 0;
  $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(index) {
    var selectedoption = $(this).attr("data-price");
    selectedoptions = parseInt(selectedoptions) + parseInt(selectedoption);
  });
  //alert(selectedoptions); get your selectedoptions value here
});
```

you need to parse your data-price value to int and no need to reinitialise your selectedoptions.